# CakePHP v 2.x Console app can't run through Cron

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, console

I have a Console Task in my CakePHP Application, which works fine if I run it in the shell manually. But it fails when I try to run it through system Cron, which is the main purpose of this Console task.

It gives me following error,

```
Error: This file has been loaded incorrectly and cannot continue.
Please make sure that /lib/Cake/Console is in your system path,
and check the cookbook for the correct usage of this command.
(http://book.cakephp.org/)
#0 /home/abc/public_html/def/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(54): ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment()
#1 /home/abc/public_html/def/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(65): ShellDispatcher->__construct(NULL)
#2 /home/abc/public_html/def/app/Console/cake.php(46): ShellDispatcher::run(NULL)
#3 {main}
```

My PHP version is 5.6.31 and I have register_argc_argv=On in my php.ini.
Even try changing

```
exec php -q ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

to

```
exec php -q -d register_argc_argv=1 ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

in Cake/Console/cake script. 
Finally, add the path to the /home/abc/public_html/def/lib/Cake/Console to the PATH as error suggested, but none of these fixed the problem it keeps saying the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you put your console task ? Usually, I created inside `app/Conosle/Command`. Not in `lib`.

Comment: Yes, it is in `app/Console/Command` and the cron task is `/home/abc/public_html/def/app/Console/cake MyShell`